# CSS display: none/block not working inside FORM

Tags: html, css

Still working on the pure CSS language switcher.

Does CSS `display: none/block` with `div` or `span` doesn't work inside a `HTML FORM`?

Here is the code:

```css
.tab {display:none}

.default-tab {display:block}

:target ~ .default-tab {display:none}

#eng:target ~ .eng,
#deu:target ~ .deu {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<a href="#eng"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flat-europe-flag/48/United-Kingdom-icon.png"></a>


<a href="#deu"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flat-europe-flag/48/Germany-icon.png"></a>

<a id="eng"></a>
<a id="deu"></a>

<div class="tab eng default-tab">Some English content</div>
<div class="tab deu">Was auf deutsch.</div><p>



<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked>
  <div class="tab eng default-tab">Male</div>
  <div class="tab deu">M&auml;nnlich</div>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
  <div class="tab eng default-tab">Female</div>
  <div class="tab deu">Weiblich</div>
</form> 

<hr>
  <div class="tab eng default-tab">Male</div>
  <div class="tab deu">M&auml;nnlich</div>
```

Works perfectly outside the form, but not inside.

Comment: Your [mcve] needs to exist in your question, not only on a third-party site

Comment: I can't tell what your question is. What are you hoping will display, and how does it differ from what is actually displaying?

Comment: To answer the actual question you asked, elements inside `<form>` are not treated differently than elements inside any other tag: `display: block` and `display: none` will work the same as anywhere else.

Comment: What's your specific question? Which elements and classes are you referring to and thinking aren't working?

Comment: `:target ~ .default-tab` will select *siblings of the target that have the class `.default-tab`*. Your `<form>` is a sibling of the `:target` links - its children are *not*. You probably want something like `:target ~ .default-tab, :target ~ form .default-tab` (You'd have to add this same idea to your `.eng` and `.deu` selections as well).  **[Here is an updated version of your fiddle that seems to work as you intend.](https://jsfiddle.net/bjqyhkqu/2/)**

Comment: Also, just to throw in my own 2 cents, I'd imagine this would be much less of a headache moving forward if you used JS to accomplish this. Relying on the sibling selector seems like a self-inflicted hamstring in the event you want to move things around in the future.

Comment: @Tyler Roper, thank you, your suggestions works perfectly. You are correct, it gets a bit more messy and I try write the same with JS. I find the language switch without page reload quite attractive.

Comment: @Tyler Roper, I tried the same in JS. I used `span` to avoid line breaks. Since I use `span` elsewhere in the code is it acceptable to use 'fantasy' tags, such as `<xyz></xyz>`? A similar language switcher in JS: https://jsfiddle.net/yello/k4p7r50t/

Comment: @yello Similar, however I'd suggest marking everything language-specific with a common class, and then one for the specific language. Like `<span class="lang eng"></span>`, and then you can do `$('.lang').hide(); $('.eng').show();` for the "English" button, and so-on. If you're going to stick with the CSS method, I'd suggest myf's answer below - it's a bit less specific than mine and likely more extensible.

Comment: @Tyler Roper, I changed everything to JS. Works nicely. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Here the final jsfiddle in JS, no CSS. I set a class for the `<span>`. Can be copy and paste into Wordpress. To avoid line breaks in WP write all `<span>` in one line. Despite the downvotes I hope one or two other people find this useful.  https://jsfiddle.net/yello/xtp8dpzL/

Answer (score 0):

The `~` selector in `a ~ b` means "all following siblings of `b`".

You probably want to affect `b`s even when they are not siblings but children of siblings (in your case, children of `form`), so you have to add `a ~ * b` to existing selector:

```
a ~ * b,
a ~ b {}
```